# KivyMD: can't bind function

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

i'm generating multiple buttons,i want to bind each button `on_release` event and each button return a unique ID to the assigned function, here's my whole code:-

```
class APP(MDApp):
    class MovieScreen(Screen):
        def on_enter(self, *args):
            pass

    def addMoreMovies(self, imdbid):
        print(imdbid)

    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '450')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '700')
    Config.write()

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls = ThemeManager()
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

    def on_start(self):
        amountOfMovies = 10

        movies = getMovie(amountOfMovies)
        for i in range(len(movies[0])):
            image = movies[1][i]
            name = movies[0][i]
            imdbid = movies[2][i]
            tile=SmartTileWithLabel()
            tile.id=str(imdbid)
            tile.bind(on_release=lambda x: APP.addMoreMovies(self,imdbid=imdbid))
            tile.source=str(image)
            tile.text=str(name)
            tile.size=(182,268)
            tile.height='240dp'
            tile.size_hint_y=None
        self.root.ids.grid.add_widget(tile)
```

the code kinda works, but all the buttons are returning the last assigned ID,

i realized that i have to change my code from

`tile.bind(on_release=lambda x: APP.addMoreMovies(self,imdbid=imdbid))`

to

`tile.bind(on_release=APP.addMoreMovies(self,imdbid=imdbid))`

so that each button instance it's own function. but when i run the code i get this following error:-

```
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 419, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
 AssertionError: None is not callable
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should use `self.addMoreMovies` instead of `APP.addMoreMovies`

Comment: sorry for that, i'll keep that in mind for my next questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_release=` needs function's name without `()` (and without arguments) so when you press button then it uses `()` to execute it.

If you use

```
on_release=APP.addMoreMovies()
```

then you execute function at start and it works like

```
result = APP.addMoreMovies() 
bind(on_release=result)
```

but `APP.addMoreMovies()` returns `None` so you have

```
result = None  # APP.addMoreMovies() 
bind(on_release=result)
```

and this gives

```
bind(on_release=None)
```

so you error `None is not callable`

---

You should keep version with `lambda` but you may have to send `imdb` in different way

```
bind(on_release=lambda x, value=imdbid: APP.addMoreMovies(self,imdbid=value))
```

and then every button should use own value